# What questions to expect during a interview to renew a contract?

Tags: interviewing

What type of questions should an employee expect during a interview to renew a contract?

Would the questions be like something that the employee faced during the 1st interview with the employer or would it be something different?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace! I had a question, this question is a bit similar to your other question at http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12632/what-questions-should-i-ask-when-asked-to-come-for-an-interview-with-regards-to? I think these two could be merged by just including that you want to see both questions you can expect and questions you can ask.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Actually they may look similar but this one ask about what employer will ask. The another question ask about what employee should ask. Two different person.

Answer (score 1):

One of the important parts of such a review/contract renewal meeting is your performance. What has been your added worth to the company, did you meet the goals you set at the beginning of the contract. In addition, if they decide to re-hire your, part of the meeting is probably going to be used to set new goals for next year (i.e. expand more into manager position, do a course to develop yourself inot a certain area, etc).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to discussing performance, the worth you bring to the contract, and goals for the year, expect to discuss your rate.

If there is fiscal pressure on the employer expect a resistance to higher rates or a reduction of hours. You need to understand your option going into the meeting. What will you do if they won't approve a increase, or they want to reduce the rate? What is the bottom rate you can accept?

If there is less pressure on them they might be open to an increase in pay or benefits. In that case what will you ask for?